# Will FAIR be able to reach the quark-gluon plasma phase transition?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, large-hadron-collider, strong-force

At low temperature and baryonic density quarks and gluons are confined in hadrons. Most physicists believe that the phase transition between hadron and the quark-gluon plasma has been reached at LHC and RHIC.

[image: 1]

Some years ago, it was discussed whether or not [a plasma could also be obtained at FAIR](http://www.fair-center.eu/public/). It would be at finite baryonic density and thus not the same order. Some people had some doubt about the possibility for FAIR to reach enough energy and density to get a plasma.

Are there any recent news from physicists? Or does anyone know if a paper is giving details about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [At the FAIR-facility](http://www.fair-center.eu/public/what-happens-at-fair/basic-science/plasma-physics.html), it will be possible to advance into ranges of plasma temperature and density that a*pproximate the conditions in giant planets, such as Jupiter.* Moreover, these studies open up the fascinating possibility of investigating the basic physics aspects of inertial confinement fusion - for many scientists a process that may represent the future energy supply for humanity.

the history of the file:

> Size: 17.1 K - Created: 30-06-08 - Modified: 02-09-15 15:56

So it does not seem to be progressing fast, still in the planning stage

There was  a recent conference there , 11-13 of July 2016,

https://indico.gsi.de/conferenceDisplay.py?confId=2164

and a 20 minute talk by David Riley  on Plasma physics but no proceedings yet. You could ask at the e-mail given as contact k.weyrich@gsi.de .

Comment: I think the plasma in giant planets such as Jupiter is not a quark-gluon plasma. This conference seems to be the most recent one though. Thank you.